# ReactJS: Removing dynamically added component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a form, where we have to add new row of component on a button click. Adding new component is working fine. Used below code to do that

```
    const onClickAddExamSection = () => {
    const uuid = getUniqueId();
    const data = [...examSections];
    data.push({
      index: uuid, data: <ScheduleExamSection key={uuid} className='row mt-4'
        index={uuid} onClickRemoveSection={onClickRemoveSection} />
    });
    setExamSections(data);
  };
```

Result will be like below image
[image]

When remove button is clicked, below function is called

```
  const onClickRemoveSection = (index) => {
    const data = [...examSections];
    const filtered = data.filter(x => x.index !== index);
    setExamSections(filtered);
  };
```

Issue I'm facing is, when I click on the remove button of one row, all the rows below that is getting removed. While debugging I found that, when it reaches **onClickRemoveSection** *examSections* already having data removed. Nowhere else we are modifying **examSections**.

Remove button is in **ScheduleExamSection** component. That part of code is like below

```
{index !== '0' ?
                    <img src={del} className="App-logo" style={{ marginLeft: '20px', paddingTop: 45 }} alt="logo" 
                    onClick={() => deleteEntry(index)} /> : <></>}


const deleteEntry = (sn) => {
    console.log('clicked ' + sn);
    onClickRemoveSection(sn);
};
```

How to tackle this issue?

Comment: you could use splice() instead of the filter, so something like:
const filtered.splice(index, 1)

Comment: @B.Wesselink, when the code reaches onClickRemoveSection, I tried to iterate through examSections. At that time it self the data is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to do this in react is the following try it out:

```
setExamSections( prev => {
    prev.splice(index, 1)
    return [...prev]
})
```

Comment: This one worked, thanks.